# IPrinciple and IIdentity in an E-commcerce app - ASP.NET MVC

Tags: asp.net-mvc

I'm trying to figure out when rolling my own custom membership provider (not inheriting from the ASP.NET membership) if I need to work with the IPrincipal and IIdentity.  I mean isn't that only used for non-public sites where you are working with a windows based account?

also I want to be creating my own cookie to store auth data, not the .ASPXAUTH cookie.

We are also creating our own Role Provider so we wouldn't be using the Context.User.IsInRole functionality I would assume with IIdentity.

Comment: May I ask why you want to do this?

Answer (score 2):

> I mean isn't that only used for non-public sites where you are working
>   with a windows based account?

Not at all. Those interfaces are used with the membership provider no matter what kind of authentication scheme you are using. For example the User property of `HttpContext` is an `IPrincipal` which contains an `Identity` property of type `IIdentity`. So no matter what kind of authentication you are using you should be working with those interfaces. Of course you could write your own custom implementations.

Comment: yea I just realized that...I always use HttpContext and yea I see now.  Duh.  We aren't using the membership provider we are rolling our own and was just making sure that our code has nothing to do related to the ASP.NET Membership provider.  In other words we are rolling our own way to do stuff and our own DB tables to auth a user.  We don't like how the ASP.NET Membership is providing this out of the box.

Comment: when you say write your own custom implementations, that is kinda what we wanna do.  We will grab the current user info from HttpContext.  I was also looking at this blog post: http://www.bradygaster.com/custom-authentication-with-mvc-3.0

Comment: @CoffeeAddict I would recommend abstracting out the user and not accessing it directly from HttpContext. This will make unit testing your controllers much easier.